# add a new column with html tags in R dataframe based on values form another column

Tags: html, r

I have a dataframe as shown below. I need to popualate some html tags based on values from these columns. Is there way?

```
asd <- data.frame(color = c("gray","red"), text1= c("something", "something1"))
```

Expected output

```
asd_new
  color       text                             html
1   gray   something        <div class="gray">something</div>
2   red    something1        <div class="red">something1</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sprintf`/`paste0` :

```
asd$html <- sprintf('<div class="%s">%s</div>', asd$color, asd$text1)
asd

#  color      text1                              html
#1  gray  something <div class="gray">something</div>
#2   red something1 <div class="red">something1</div>
```

Comment: Thanks,,,,,,,,,,,, But why cannot i use just ````asd$html <- tags$div(class = asd$text1, asd$color1)````

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that piece of code is supposed to do.

Comment: Np.. Just last doubt. sprintf is creating double quotes between strings. For example "gray". Can we have single quote instead. Like 'gray' ???

Comment: Yes, you can change quotes around. `asd$html <- sprintf("<div class='%s'>%s</div>", asd$color, asd$text1)`

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
asd %>% mutate(html = str_c('<div class="',color,'">',text1,'</div>'))
  color      text1                              html
1  gray  something <div class="gray">something</div>
2   red something1 <div class="red">something1</div>
```